# Logic error while creating sentence from position

Tags: python

I created this program that asks to enter a list of position into a file than saves it as a list and also into another file the the user has to enter the list of words every position has. For example if i enter:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

and

```
 this is a repeated sentence
```

the outpur should be

```
this is a repeated sentence this is a repeated sentence
```

However when i run my code i get the list of position instead

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

here is my code:

```
import subprocess
process_position = subprocess.Popen(["notepad","list_of_numbers.txt"])
process_position.wait()
positions = []
with open("list_of_numbers.txt","r") as f:
    positions = f.read().split()

process_words = subprocess.Popen(["notepad","list_of_words.txt"])
process_words.wait()
sentence = ""
with open("list_of_numbers.txt","r") as s:
    sentence= s.read().split()


mapping = {}

for (position, word) in zip(positions, sentence):
    mapping[position] = word


output = [mapping[position] for position in positions]

print(' '.join(output))
```

Comment: Well `positions` does contain **strings**, not **ints**...

Comment: Use `mapping[int(position)] = word`...

Comment: i tried but i get a syntax error

Comment: And a syntax error is a logical error...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused. The `position` list, if I understand correctly, is a list of word-positions you want to print, in order. So you don't want to `zip` it together with the words from `sentence.`

Instead, simply look up the words in the `sentence` list using the integer value of the `position` numbers:

```
result = []
for p in map(int, position):
    result.append(sentence[p])

print(' '.join(result))
```

Or, squeezing a little bit:

```
print(' '.join([sentence[p] for p in map(int, position)]))
```

Comment: it doesn`t i get an error "list index out of range"

Comment: Try using 0-based positions instead of 1-based. Alternatively, use `sentence[p-1]` instead of `sentence[p]`.